# How to correctly call ComponentDialog from another ComponentDialog

Tags: node.js, botframework

I've been battling with this over the last day, can't seem to get it to work correctly. I would share code but I feel it might confuse matters.

I've created a few `ComponentDialogs` that are needed to be included in other `ComponentDialogs` including the main `bot.js`.

*ComponentDialogA* is being imported into the main `bot.js` which gets called fine when I do a replaceDialog or beginDialog. But when I try can call *ComponentDialogB* from *ComponentDialogA* it just returns to the last point of *ComponentDialogA* and fails to hit *ComponentDialogB*.

So my sub questions are as follows:

1. Do I need a custom state accessor for each ComponentDialog in order
   to do what I want to achieve or is that just for storing specific
   data related to that dialog as opposed to the actual dialog position
2. Related to the first do I need a new dialogSet per ComponentDialog to
   handle child ComponentDialogs, to use `this.dialogs.add` instead of
   `this.addDialog`?
3. Am I just being dimwitted and messed up my code
   somewhere?

I'll try and simplify my code and share later.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is currently a limitation in `v4.2.x` version of the libraries that prevent `ComponentDialog`s from accessing dialogs outside of itself in *any* way. This means that the dialogs inside of a `ComponentDialog` can only ever begin dialogs that are siblings to them within that `ComponentDialog` and never access the outside world.

[In `4.3.x` timeframe it will be possible for a `ComponentDialog` to begin a dialog "up" its ancestry chain as well](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/5242). This means that, for your scenario, if both `ComponentDialogA` and `ComponentDialogB` were registered in the same parent `DialogSet`, `ComponentDialogA` *would* be able to call `beginDialog('ComponentDialogB' ...)` and it would find it.

To be clear though, you will still not be able to address individual dialogs within `ComponentDialog`s from the outside. Meaning, if your `ComponentDialogB` had a `SubDialogX` inside of it, something outside, such as `ComponentDialogA`, cannot start *that* "inner" dialog explicitly. Make sense?

Comment: It does and it turns out what I was trying to achieve would have worked if it wasn't for the fact that the answer to my third sub question was true :D. Turned out the component dialog I was trying to triggered had an error in the code... perfect valid javascript but no bot errors etc... serves me right for not using TypeScript. Problem resolved itself but I will mark this as correct as it's great information about what to look forward to in 4.3.x.

Comment: @SamTassell did you manage to get it to work defining a new DialogSet inside ComponentDialogA? Although the answer from Drew is correct, it would be useful if you share your solution while we wait for 4.3.x